Can I install an app in win10 without UAC?
I don't know much about how Windows works, but whenever I try to install a program, the UAC prompt comes up and it worries me about how much power is granted to the installer.
I downloaded an installer, but I only want to run this program as a user, not as admin. Is there a way to install it without allowing the installer to change anything important (that would require admin privileges)? I usually use Sandboxie, but this program isn't running sandboxed, it crashes.
On the same note, is it safer not to install a program in the C:\Program Files folder, or it doesn't really matter where it's installed if the UAC authorization was given?

It hasn’t been possible to disable UAC fully for more than 10 years. If an installer is requesting elevated permissions then there is no way to bypass that requirement. It’s perfectly safe to install software to Program Files, even if you were to change the installation directory, the installer would still need elevated permissions

@Ramhound thank you! Is this still true even if later on I don't run the program with elevated permissions? For example, if I install it to a different drive, D, if I don't run it with elevated permissions I think it can't access Program Files. But if I install it to Program Files would it also get access to other folders in Program Files without running it as administrator?

Installer (install.exe for example) - is just a program to setup files and settings for you.
In most cases it unpacks archive with files and copies it to the destination folder (before it creates it). Some folders are system like Windows or Program Files, thats why UAC asks elevation to get access to it.
Another case - is access to registry hives like HKLM.
But you can try to unpack this install.exe (if it is simple archive) or find PORTABLE version of this application.
If you have enough knowledge, you can try to install this app on another machine, using UAC and then copy files to the destination machine. Maybe this app could be launched there (if it does not need elevation for some of its tasks).

Thanks! This is something I thought about afterwards, I could still install it with Sandboxie or in a VM and then copy the installed files and see if it works like this. I ended up giving up and just installing it, seeing what changed in Sandboxie told me it shouldn't matter (there were some registry changes to HKLM, but they didn't seem particularly worrisome from what I could understand)
